# In Sql Server, how can I update Table A record values from multiple records of Table B

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, inner-join, multiple-tables

### TableA:
ID varchar,
Name1 varchar,
Name2 varchar

### TableB:
ID varchar,
Name varchar,
Type varchar

I want to update Name1 and Name2 in TableA from TableB when they have the same ID value:
when TableB.Type = '1', then only update TableA.Name1 with TableB.Name;
when TableB.Type = '2', then only update TableA.Name2 with TableB.Name;

I tried something like below but seems only Name1 get updated:

```
update TableA
set TableA.Name1 = case when TableB.Type = '1' then TableB.Name end,
TableA.Name2 = case when TableB.Type = '2' then TableB.Name end
from TableA join TableB on TableA.ID = Table B.ID
```

Your comments would be appreciated.

---

below is a runnable example to describe the case:

```
create table #AAA
(
    ID      varchar(1000),  
    Name1   varchar(1000),
    Name2   varchar(1000)
)
insert #AAA values ('99', null, null);

create table #BBB
(
    ID      varchar(1000),  
    Name    varchar(1000),
    Type    varchar(1000)
)
insert #BBB values ('99', 'x', '1');
insert #BBB values ('99', 'y', '2');

update a
set a.Name1 = case when b.Type = '1' then b.Name else a.Name1 end,
    a.Name2 = case when b.Type = '2' then b.Name else a.Name2 end
from #AAA a inner join #BBB b on a.ID = b.ID

select * from #AAA
```

*before the update, the data in #AAA is as below:
ID=99; Name1=null; Name2=null;

*after the update, the data in #AAA is as below:
ID=99; Name1=x; Name2=null;

Comment: Please make this a complete question by adding sample data before and after the update.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I added my test data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking of doing conditional aggregation first on the B table, followed by an update join:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, MAX(CASE WHEN Type = '1' THEN Name END) AS Name1,
               MAX(CASE WHEN Type = '2' THEN Name END) AS Name2
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY ID
)

UPDATE a
SET Name1 = b.Name1, Name2 = b.Name2
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN cte b ON a.ID = B.ID;
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I did add the else part in my previous test but I got the same result, only the Name1 value get updated as expected but Name2 keeps null value.

Comment: @AaronZ Please try my updated answer.  The sample data made things a lot clearer, by the way.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim! I changed the 'TableB  b' in your code to 'cte b' and it works pretty good!

Comment: I am curious if there is a way in only one step update, since the real TableB is bit of complicated. Anyway, a working solution is the best.